# Can't get Users with roles Asp.net MVC5 identity 2.2.1 dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

**Hello everybody!**

After reading [MRebati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3563665/mrebati) tip from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097603/cant-get-users-with-roles-asp-net-mvc5-identity-2-2-1), I searched and understod thanks to this [blog](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/) the importance of not mixing unity and OWIN also how to dependency inject ASP.net identity.

So first of all I don't want to be marked as asking the same question even though I am, but now my code has changed a bit compare to the last question.

Anyway now I'm getting a different error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Which means that I'm still getting null when calling my custom Usermanager.

My desired result is to get a list of all my users with their receptive roles :

XXXXXX ------ Admin

YYYYYY ------ Manager

Info about my project:

MVC: 5.2.3

Identity: 2.2.1

Entity framework : code first 2.2.1

Also I'm trying to use dependency injection with Unity.

Here's my code :

Controller :

```
public ActionResult GetUsersWithRoles(string roleName)
        {

            ViewBag.UsersWithRoles = _userManager.GetUsersInRole(context, roleName);


            return View(ViewBag.UsersWithRoles);
        }
```

My custom usermanager inside IdentityConfig.cs:

```
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
                : base(store)
            {
/// the create part which is moved from the default /// 
          public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> GetUsersInRole(ApplicationDbContext context, string roleName)
                {
                    if (context !=null && roleName !=null)
                    {
                        var roles = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == roleName);
                        if (roles.Any())
                        {
                            var roleId = roles.First().Id;
                            return from user in context.Users
                                   where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)
                                   select user;
                        }
                    }

                return null;
            }
```

Finally my view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetUsersWithRoles", "Roles"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <h3>Roles for this user </h3>

    foreach (IQueryables in ViewBag.UsersWithRoles)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>@s</td>
        </tr>
    }


}
```

Here's my unityConfig.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using eCommerce.DAL.Repositories;
using eCommerce.Model;
using eCommerce.Contracts.Repositories;
using eCommerce.WebUI.Controllers;
using eCommerce.WebUI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace eCommerce.WebUI.App_Start
{

    public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });


        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return container.Value;
        }
        #endregion


        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<Product>, ProductRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<Basket>, BasketRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<Voucher>, VoucherRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<VoucherType>, VoucherTypeRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<BasketVoucher>, BasketVoucherRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<BasketItem>, BasketItemsRepository>();
            //container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
            container.RegisterType <IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));


        }
    }
}
```

Here's the constructor for the RolesController.cs :

```
 private ApplicationDbContext context;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public RolesController(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUserManager _userManager)
        {

            this.context = context;
            this._userManager = _userManager;
        }
```

Here's my startup.cs:
a

```
ssembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(eCommerce.WebUI.Startup))]
namespace eCommerce.WebUI
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()); // <-
            DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

        }



    }
}
```

Here's my Global.asax :

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            if (!context.Users.Any(user => user.UserName == "Email@hotmail.com"))
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
                var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = "Email@hotmail.com" };
                userManager.Create(applicationUser, "Password");

                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

                userManager.AddToRole(applicationUser.Id, "Admin");

            }
        }

    }
```

Create method from my rolesController:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = collection["RoleName"]
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where are you getting the NullReferenceException? And you need to amend your question to show how you're setting up your dependencies with Unity.

Comment: I have included the unityconfig

Comment: I'm still not seeing enough here. I don't know what class your `GetUsersInRole` method is in, or what interfaces it implements. I don't know what the constructor of your controller looks like (assuming constructor injection.). I don't see how you're registering the Unity container with ASP.NET. Think about the whole chain of things that need to be shown for someone to diagnose your issue. Read over [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done, maybe?  Thank you for the link!
Interesting read.

Comment: The one thing you've still left out is telling ASP.NET MVC about Unity so that it can use it to resolve dependencies when creating the constructors. Do you have a line like `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()));` in your code somewhere?

Comment: First of all I'm sorry for being a total dumb nut, but perhaps you also need to see my starup.cs if I understand you correctly.

I'll update the post again. But I have a different version.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC won't know to use Unity unless you tell it to. That's where [DependencyResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) comes in. Usually for ASP.NET MVC and each DI container, there's a "bootstrap" package that handles calling the `DependencyResolver` for you, in Unity's case [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/). Do you have that package installed? And what exactly was throwing the NullReferenceException in your code?

Comment: Aha I see that makes sense, Yes I have the boostrap package installed and changed : 

 app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()); 

to

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer()));

But still I'm getting the same error and it happens in my view in the foreach statement.

thank you.

Comment: So if you made it that far, Dependency Injection is probably set up correctly. What exactly is null? That's always most important thing to figure out with a NullReferenceException. I've noticed in your view that you're doing a `string` in your `foreach` statement, even though `ViewBag.UsersWithRoles` is an `IQueryable<ApplicationUser>`. So you've got a mismatch there. Never use ViewBag - pass information from controller to view via a strongly typed model. Also, `IQueryable` being passed to a view is not a good idea, this causes your view to do data access.

Comment: Hmm.. it makes sense the points that you have pointed. The problem is that I'm really struggling with the whole process, I never done something so advanced before(went to a bad video game programming education at university) 

But really what I need help with is understanding how I should write the controller in a right way and also passing it to the view.

Thank you // I have searched high and low.

Comment: This is just an app as a learning exercise? I'd start simpler. Don't do Identity Framework. Just code your own simple user repository and use a DI container to inject it into a controller. I used Ninject, which is a little messier, but you can see an example of that [here](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/masonogcrm). You can clone the project to your computer, open up the solution, and run it without any configuration.

Comment: Yeah it's a learning exercise / future portfolio website (I really want to get a job / working at a convenient store atm.. ), so I was hoping to have this app as a working example of what I know and.. when chatting with you realize somewhat understands when it comes to MVC and DI. 

Also it feels bad just giving up, when every other part works(login/regi add/remove products baskets and so on..) 

But it's super weird why the other solutions won't work with me..

I'll take a look at you example , and hopefully learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Better to keep the reference to DbContext in your `UserManager`:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationDbContext context, /*... other parameters*/) : base(store)
    {
        this.context = context;
        //... other configuration bits
    }

    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roleName));
        }

        var role = context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);

        if (role == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Role with this name not found: {roleName}");
        }

        var users = context.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id)).ToList();

        return users;
    }

    // the rest of User manager methods
}
```

In your controller avoid using `ViewBag` - it is just not a good practice. Also, as already been mentioned never pass `IQueryable` to your view. Roughly speaking `IQueryable` is a SQL query, but IEnumerable is a collection of objects. View needs to know only about objects. So your controller can look like this:

```
public class UsersWithRoleController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager userManager;

    public UsersWithRoleController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public ActionResult GetUsersWithRoles(string roleName)
    {
        var users = userManager.GetUsersInRole(roleName);

        var viewModel = new GetUsersWithRolesViewModel()
        {
            RoleName = roleName,
            Users = users,
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

}

public class GetUsersWithRolesViewModel
{
    public String RoleName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And view will be:

```
@model IoCIdentity.Controllers.GetUsersWithRolesViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

<h2>List of users in role @Model.RoleName</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var user in @Model.Users)
    {
        <li>@user.UserName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

You can get the full sample in my [github](https://github.com/trailmax/IoCIdentitySample/blob/usersWithRole/IoCIdentity/Controllers/UsersWithRoleController.cs). Though I've not tested it properly - my db is broken at the moment -(

Comment: Sorry but still the same problem, could it because of what I have written in my Global.asax file?  I mean your code makes perfect sense, and easy to follow.  It's weird that it doesn't even enter the method Getuserswithroles when I debug. I'll take a look at your github.

Comment: @Habbex You'll need to find what exactly is null and where it is. Otherwise it's impossible for us to help. I'd start from removing users/roles initialisation in `Global.asax.cs` and then stripping down the solution to bare minimum.

Comment: Yeah that's the plan right now, i'll contact you if something comes up.
Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Damn.. My project in specific the user to role management is more of a Viewbag-View-Controller than Model-View-Controller after reading you post about [Asp.Net MVC ViewBag is BAD!!!](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/asp-net-mvc-viewbag-is-bad/).

Strangely enough I can pass and get all my users into a dropboxlist through the view, as the same way as I get roles from the tutorial site which got me in this mess to begin with.. Damn I just didn't know the thing about viewbags and such.. 

So I'll search for a more correct way to do the user roles assignment, and retry again.. thank you!

Comment: I have move you suggested code to have a separate view this in order to better understand, and also get rid of the viewbags messing the debug process. When done, the code finally calls the method GetUsersInRoles, but seams not to be able to find RoleName.  And stops at : `throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roleName));`

With the following error message : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: roleName. I'm suspecting it has to with the create new role method which I got from the tutorial site. I'll update and post my github soon.

Comment: @Habbex that error says that your `roleName` is empty - nothing is passed into this method. Most likely there is no parameter passed into the controller action when you receive the request